# Spring Boot & QueryDSL with compilation error: due to QClass symbol not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, maven-3, jhipster, querydsl

I am new to Querydsl , but I am having problems with generating Q classes.
I get a lot of errors that a Q'class' cannot be resolved , like this :

```
Cannot find symbol class QProduct
```

the code

```
private final QProduct qProduct = QProduct.product;
```

my project is built with :
spring-boot.version : 2.0.8 ; 
Java version : 1.8 ; 
Maven version : 3.0  ;
Hibernate version : 5.2.17 ;
postgresql : 42.2.5 ;

i'm use "maven-apt-plugin" for generated Q class.
**porn.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

I have already tried this solution but the problem persists

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <goals>
            <goal>process</goal>
        </goals>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/querydsl/java
            </outputDirectory>
            <processor>com.querydsl.apt.QuerydslAnnotationProcessor</processor>
            <options>
                <querydsl.logInfo>true</querydsl.logInfo>
                <querydsl.listAccessors>false</querydsl.listAccessors>
                <querydsl.useGetters>true</querydsl.useGetters>
                <querydsl.unknownAsEmbeddable>true</querydsl.unknownAsEmbeddable>
            </options>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

I looked at other topic similar to mine but their solution does not work on my project

What is wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Why tagging your question with JHipster?

Comment: my project is also built with JHipster Framework which includes angular and spingboot

Comment: Why using `provided` scope? Why using 4.2.1 and not 5.0.0? I see you're using Hibernate 5.2 so querydsl 5 should work. Also you did not say when you were getting these errors: at compile time or runtime? If it's runtime, I suspect it's because dependencies are not `provided`.

Comment: I get the errors while compiling, debugging and executing.
For version 4.2.1 of querydsl, I didn't choose it, it's a rework of the app .
I use the app to compile, test and run locally before deploying remotely to the server..
I used 'provided' scope so as not to insert it into the generated war and because it would conflict with the one provided by the application server.

Do you think i have to change to 'compile' scope for run locally?

Comment: Finally, I think `provided` is fine for the APT as this is what they use in doc http://querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.2.1/reference/html_single/#intro So when you run maven compile, do you see the APT being run and generating classes in target directory ? I noted that your `outputDirectory` is not configured 
 to `target/generated-sources/java` as documented, it might be a reason why compiler does not find them

Comment: Obviously, I note that the 'generated-sources' directory did not contain generated files.
But strangely, by removing the 'provided' scope as you sayed, it works !!
i don't understand ^_^
but thank you very much for your help